# list comprehension fail, cannot show None

Tags: python

```
a = []
b = []
c = []
d = []
a = input('Enter first  row (enter 0 for space): ')
b = input('Enter second row (enter 0 for space): ')
c = input('Enter third  row (enter 0 for space): ')
d = input('Enter fourth row (enter 0 for space): ')

start = [int(a[0]),int(a[2]),int(a[4]),int(a[6]),
         int(b[0]),int(b[2]),int(b[4]),int(b[6]),
         int(c[0]),int(c[2]),int(c[4]),int(c[6]),
         int(d[0]),int(d[2]),int(d[4]),int(d[6])]

[None if x==1 else x for x in start]

start
```

Here is my code, I try to input some value like (1 2 3 4) and save it into a list, then I want to use list comprehension to turn each 1 into `None`. But It can't change into `None` when I print it.

Comment: So apparently, you try to input a matrix like of something. Why don't we start by doing this correctly? There are plenty of ways to read a .txt file, or even an excel or .csv file.(could you detail a bit what you are trying to achieve)

Comment: basically what are you trying to do? can you explain a bit more?

Comment: `a = []` et al. don't do anything useful; you immediately overwrite those values with the strings returned by `input`. The list comprehension doesn't modify `start` in-place; it creates a *new* list which you promptly discard.

Answer (score 1):

The list comprehension doesn't modify `start` in-place; you need a regular `for` to execute a series of assignment statements instead.

```
for i, x in enumerate(start):
    if x == 1:
        start[i] = None
```

Answer (score 0):

Or, following chepner's answer, just try

```
start = [None if x==1 else x for x in start]
start
```